# Cannot get reflect metadata of class instance

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

I'm trying to retrieve the reflect-metadata from the instance of a class. The examples on the [docs](https://rbuckton.github.io/reflect-metadata/) shows that it should be possible but I'm getting `undefined`. However if I request the metadata from the class itself, I get back the data, same with the method.

For eg, this is the full example script:

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

const metadataKey = 'some-key'

@Reflect.metadata(metadataKey, 'hello class')
class C {
  @Reflect.metadata(metadataKey, 'hello method')
  get name(): string {
    return 'text'
  }
}

let obj = new C()
let classInstanceMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, obj)
console.log(classInstanceMetadata) // undefined

let classMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, C)
console.log(classMetadata) // hello class

let methodMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, obj, 'name')
console.log(methodMetadata) // hello method
```

My goal is to get back some data in the `classInstanceMetadata` that lets me associate it with the class type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that I'll need to use a decorator and then define the metadata on the target's prototype.

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

const metadataKey = 'some-key'

export const Decorate = (): ClassDecorator => {
  return (target: Function) => {
    @Reflect.metadata(metadataKey, 'hello class', target.prototype)
  }
}

@Decorate()
class C {
  get name(): string {
    return 'text'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can omit `()` at the decorator, so `@Decorate` would be enough. Also, reflect has **specific metadata design keys** that depend on the use of the metadata/decorator:

1. Type metadata = `"design:type"`
2. Parameter type metadata => `"design:paramtypes"`
3. Return type metadata => `"design:returntype"`